# Risk scenarios when hosting KEK in Google Cloud KMS HSM backended

Tags: keys

For some time now, we have been assessing the risks from a GDPR perspective when data (data-at-rest) in the Google Cloud is fully encrypted using native means. This means that we create both the KEK and the DEK completely with Google Cloud KMS and encrypt the storage buckets with it.
Also, we are not currently subject to any regulatory requirements that enforce separation based on CSEK or CMEK.
It would help me a lot if someone could share his experience in this area, opinions and thoughts are also very welcome.

Thx

Comment: Encrypted PII is still PII, since it can be decrypted. A legal advice forum would probably be a better fit, but AFAIK (I'm not a lawyer) the GDPR cares about whether stored data can be attributed to a person by any means, including decryption or practical de-anonymization.